# PyQt: class object deleting, calling destructors but memory not freeing

Tags: python, qt, memory, memory-leaks, pyqt

I am creating a tool using `pyQt` but facing memory leakage issue.

When I delete an object containing python and pyQt member variables from UI using my own trash, it calls up the destructor of the respective class. But when I run 'top' command from terminal the memory is not freed and keeps on occupying as long as I use the applications and finally crashes up.

Comment: Show us a small program that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Usually these problems occur because the C++ object is still being referenced to. If you've added the QObject to a QT class hierarchy, it won't be destroyed until the referencer is deleted, or the reference is broken. I'm puzzled what you mean by destructor - is this actually the C++ destructor or Python __del__?

Comment: The destructor is the python del method.
Yes i too find that the QObject is not deleting due to some issue. But I am not able to find a way how to delete the same and free memory.

Comment: why not share some codes? i am certain there is a reference somewhere to the object

Comment: Explicit memory management while using Python generally indicates a more underlying issue. I think a more clear example of your use case and some minimal code to demonstrate the issue would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

I already faced this problem before. 
I used this approach and it worked fine for me:

```
widget.setParent(None)
widget.deleteLater()
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT:

Also see this one please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245816/6337523